# Unable to parse JSON Schema and resolve the reference

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jsonschema

I am having one JSON Schema with ref. I am trying to resolve all the ref using `JsonSchemaResolver`. But, unfortunately , ref is not resolved and getting an error as below.

I am trying to get the substituted JSON by resolving all the ref.

**Code:**

```
        var schemaFileContents = File.ReadAllText(schemaFileName);
        JsonSchemaResolver resolver = new JsonSchemaResolver();
        var result = JsonSchema.Parse(schemaFileContents, resolver);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**JSON Schema:**

```
{
  "$schema": "YYYYYYY",
  "id": "XXXXXX",
  "title": "Current Employee Details",
  "description": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "EMP": {
      "title": "Employee ",
      "description": "Details of the Employee",
      "$ref": "#/definitions/Employee"
    }},
    "definitions": {
      "EmployeeAddress": {
        "title": "Address",
        "description": "EmployeeAddress - Present Address",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "type": {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
              "EmployeeAddress"
            ]
          },
          "address": {
            "title": "Address",
            "type": "string"
          },
          "postalCode": {
            "title": "Postal Code",
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "postalCode",
          "address"
        ]
      },

      "Employee": {
        "title": "Party",
        "description": "Employee Details",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "firstName": {
            "title": "First name",
            "type": "string"
          },
          "address": {
            "title": "Employee Address",
            "$ref": "#/definitions/EmployeeAddress"
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "firstName"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

**Error:**

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Can not convert Array to Boolean.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.op_Explicit(JToken value)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JsonSchemaBuilder.ProcessSchemaProperties(JObject schemaObject)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JsonSchemaBuilder.BuildSchema(JToken token)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JsonSchemaBuilder.ResolveReferences(JsonSchema schema)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JsonSchemaBuilder.ResolveReferences(JsonSchema schema)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JsonSchemaBuilder.Read(JsonReader reader)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JsonSchema.Read(JsonReader reader, JsonSchemaResolver resolver)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JsonSchema.Parse(String json, JsonSchemaResolver resolver)
```

Comment: So, basically you want values of each object in this json ?

Comment: I want to get the resulted JSON with all the ref substituted value.

Comment: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/RefJsonSchemaResolver.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using `json schema V4` but `JsonSchemaResolver` expects the `json schema V3`. The difference between them is in `required` field. Try to use it on the property level with `bool` value instead of the array value on the higher level:

```
"address": {
    "title": "Address",
    "type": "string",
    "required": true
}
```

According to [docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/RefJsonSchemaResolver.htm) `JsonSchemaResolver` is obsolete. To use json schema with the latest standards you need to use the [separate package](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema). Use the `JSchemaPreloadedResolver`, see the example [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/RefJsonSchemaResolver.htm)

Comment: Thanks albert for the suggestion. But, How should I resolve the json schema V4? Whether I need to use any other library?

Comment: I have tried with the above mentioned sample example.But , only "type": "object", "properties": { "EMP": { "$ref": "XXXXXX#/definitions/Employee" }  alone is moving towards last portion and definition section is moving after description. still I could see "$ref" values are not substituted correctly. I need to resolve the $ref within the same JSON.

Comment: what is meant by "$ref values are not substituted correctly" and "resolve the $ref"?  Have you tried to test the validity of a real `employee` object with your scheme? Does it work correctly?

Answer (score 2):

JsonSchemaResolver is now deprecated. Try below and use Newtonsoft.Json.Schema NuGet

```
var schemaFileContents = File.ReadAllText(schemaFileName);
JSchemaPreloadedResolver resolver = new JSchemaPreloadedResolver();
var result = JSchema.Parse(schemaFileContents, resolver);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```